# How to dynamically use require.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, module, requirejs

I want to dynamically use require.js. Something like this

```
$("button").click(function() {
    require(["A", "B"],  function(A, B) {

    });
});

button.click();  // <-- first click should load A and B
button.click();  // <-- should not run while A and B have both not loaded
// A and B now loaded
button.click();  // <-- should not re-download A and B, should just re-use A and B
```

Does anyone know how to do this? Is this kind of thing already supported in require.js?

Thanks

Comment: require.js certainly does not load things again it already has loaded. And I imagine they are also keeping track of what's currently loaded. You can always look at the code and set breakpoints.

Comment: Even assuming, they don't re-download A and B, is there a best way to check if A and B are still being downloaded for the first time?

Comment: I don't want to trigger a second redownload of A and B, and callback twice, while the first A and B is still downloading.

Comment: So you don't want the callback be executed every time the button is clicked? Why is that? What's the purpose of the button? How about disabling the button for the duration you don't want it to do something?

Comment: actually nevermind, the callback should be executed, but just wanted to make sure A and B doesn't redownload twice.

Comment: require.js already takes care of that.